# how to create foreign key unique to one of 2 tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got 2 tables A, B
I have order id belonging to only one of them.

How to create a foreign key in postgres table to point to either tableA or tableB

```
CREATE TABLE tableC(
        orderId INT,
        clientName varchar(50),
        clientAge integer,
        CONSTRAINT fk_const
        FOREIGN KEY(orderId)
        REFERENCES tableA(orderId));
```

Can someone please help how to modify if the orderId is in another table ie tableB? I am working on postgres.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have an entity, such as `order_id`, then you should have a table where this is the primary key.  One table, not two.

Answer (score 1):

## Direct answer

You can't create foreign key that points to several tables.

Not in postgresql and not in any other RDBMS that supports SQL 2003 (IIRC).

## Possible workarounds

It's possible to a dissect `order_id` into a separate table and point all other tables to this table with foreign keys.

It's possible to create a function that checks existence of value of `order_id` and use it in a check constraint.

If those tables are same in structure, and  if they could be defined as partitions of  partitioned table - starting from PostgreSQL 12 it should be possible to define FK.

So, workarounds exists, not of them hard to recommend without knowing circumstances.